# Approach to save many to many relationship in case select all values

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I have Countries mapped to Products as many to many relationships. As a result a new mapping table is created with `product_id` and `country_id`. If a Product is saved then multiple `country_id`s are stored in new row against `product_id`, which is fine in case if there are 20 or 30 countries chosen.

But if there is select all option which contains almost 300 values, is it good to go with this approach? or I should use a flag to identify that it is for all values(Countries).

Comment: I will go for new mapping table with multiple rows as it will be quick for querying. (assuming ids are indexed)

Comment: What should happen if a new country is added? Should it be automatically matched to all products with the "Select All" option selected? If so, then you would need a flag; even if you also had many-to-many records, you would need a way to know to add them for new countries. In this case, I'd look at the flag as indicating if the product is restricted to only certain countries, and use the many to many table to just hold countries with ties to restricted products. I worked for years with a system with this set-up, and it worked fairly well,

Comment: Second, is the intent for select all to be represented visually - that is to say, for there to be an "All Countries" checkbox, or a specific option in a select list that says "All Countries"? If so, you want the flag even if you'll have explicit entries for a given product with all countries in the many-to-many table, to avoid having to confirm that the product really has a connection to every current country when determining how the check box/select list should displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a flag in the products table assume it's a bit data type and set to True which means that product is related to all countries, no doubt you will have less record in the database but your query becomes a bit complex.

If you go with the first approach using the regular joins on foreign keys would also solve the problem with simple queries.

I would prefer to go with a proper many-to-many relationship approach with proper indexes, avoid updates and simple query joins. However if the need arise of having a helper column to say this product is applicable in all countries then I would add it but only if the issue arise.